# Manipulating Dictionary of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Name1  Number1  Name2  Number2  Group
 R       1        G       5       1
 B       EXP      Y       9       2
 Y       225      L       185     2
 F       17       D       2       2
 H       259      G       175     3 
 X       172      Q       EXP     3
```

I am trying to search through each "Group" and see if any of the numbers in **either** Number column fall within a certain range. If there exists one value in the group in this range, I want to append **ALL** names in the group to a list. One big hurdle is that the Number columns can contain the occasional string, and these are to be handled the same way a number out of range would be.

In this example we will say the range is 200-300

The resulting list after searching the groups would be:

```
L = [B,Y,Y,L,F,D,H,G,X,Q]
```

Notice that no names from group 1 were included in the list because group one did not contain any values in the Number1/Number2 columns between the specified range.

My code so far:

```
newList = {}
dict_of_groups = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby('Group')}
for df in dict_of_groups.values()
    if df[df['Number1'] | df['Number2'] > 199]: #how do I specify AND < 300 here?
        a = df['Number1'].values.tolist()
        b = df['Number2'].values.tolist()
        newList.update(a,b)
```

I am a little confused on how to effectively operate on each dataframe in the dict_of_dataframes. Any advice on how to best work with these groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some invalid values in your columns, which must be converted to valid numeric values in order to perform efficient comparison.  You have a couple options here, you can either work with `pandas` operations only, and perform a slower `groupby`, or you can drop down to `numpy` for a very efficient solution.

***Option 1***
`stack` + `unstack` + `groupby` + `transform`

---

```
names = df.filter(like='Name').to_numpy()

m = (pd.to_numeric(df.filter(like='Number').stack(), errors='coerce')
      .between(200, 300).unstack())

mask = m.groupby(df['Group']).transform('any').any(1)

names[mask].ravel().tolist()
```

```
['B', 'Y', 'Y', 'L', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'G', 'X', 'Q']
```

---

***Option 2***
A faster `numpy` solution using `np.add.at` and some masking

```
a = df.filter(like='Name').to_numpy().ravel()
b = df.filter(like='Number').to_numpy().ravel()
c = np.repeat(df['Group'].to_numpy(), a.shape[0] // df.shape[0])
n = pd.to_numeric(b, errors='coerce')


f = np.zeros(c.max()+1, dtype=int)
m = np.logical_and(n >= 200, n <= 300)
np.add.at(f, c, m)

mask = f[c].astype(bool)

a[mask]
```

```
array(['B', 'Y', 'Y', 'L', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'G', 'X', 'Q'], dtype=object)
```

***Timings***

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit chris_stack()
22.7 ms ± 1.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit chris_numpy()
11.9 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)\

%timeit quang()
16.7 ms ± 101 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit jezrael()
78.5 ms ± 685 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for reshape, then test per groups with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) and [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), so possible filter column `Name`:

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['Name','Number'],i=['index','Group'],j='drop')

s = pd.to_numeric(df['Number'], errors='coerce').between(200, 300)

L = df.loc[s.groupby(level=1).transform('any'), 'Name'].tolist()
print (L)
['B', 'Y', 'Y', 'L', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'G', 'X', 'Q']
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df)
                 Name Number
index Group drop            
0     1     1       R      1
            2       G      5
1     2     1       B    EXP
            2       Y      9
2     2     1       Y    225
            2       L    185
3     2     1       F     17
            2       D      2
4     3     1       H    259
            2       G    175
5     3     1       X    172
            2       Q    EXP
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Chris' answer, but without `stack`/`unstack`

```
s1 = pd.to_numeric(df['Number1'], errors='coerce')
s2 = pd.to_numeric(df['Number2'], errors='coerce')

s = s1.between(200,300) | s2.between(200,300)

df.loc[s.groupby(df['Group']).transform('any'), ['Name1', 'Name2']].values.ravel()
```

gives:

```
array(['B', 'Y', 'Y', 'L', 'F', 'D', 'H', 'G', 'X', 'Q'], dtype=object)
```

Note: if you have more than 2 name/number columns, you could consider transform the data frame to long format.

Comment: I am a little confused, how do you "use" the array object. I am trying to get the values in a list.

Comment: @MaxB you can always do `list(array_object)` to get the list. Just curious, how do you want to "use" your list?

Comment: @QuangHoang ah I see, sorry for the confusion. I have another list that I am going to compare to this list for differences essentially.

Comment: in that case, you almost certainly want to look at `set`, unless the two list are of the same length and you want to compare them element-wise.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yeah I know, forgot to put it in the question but didn't want to change it and confuse people. :P